# Multiple c++ Eclipse Helios Projects with Source in a Single Directory

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I'm working on a legacy codebase that has all the code for multiple c++ executables and static libraries in a single folder.

I'm wondering if its possible to create projects in Eclipse Helios for each of these without moving the corresponding source to its own directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Eclipse projects anywhere, then in each of the project do:

`RMB on project->New->Folder`, expand `Advanced>>`, select `Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)` and browse to the directory where your shared sources are located.

Or you can have one project with multiple targets instead.